# I don't understand why my apex test isn't covering my trigger

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have a fairly simple use case -- if a field isn't set and it's updated by a member in a group, set the field with a difference between 2 times.

The code looks like this:

```
trigger FirstTouch on FeedComment (after insert, after update){
    List<Case> updates = new List<case>();
    List<Id> feedItemList = new List<id>();
    Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Support_Team_Member__c = true]);
    for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
        if(userMap.containsKey(fc.InsertedById)){
            feedItemList.add(fc.ParentID);
        }
    }

    //NOT COVERED START 
    for(Case c : [Select Id from Case where Id IN (Select ParentId FROM FeedItem WHERE Id IN: feedItemList)]){
        if(c.Support_First_response_minutes__c == null && c.Case_Assigned_To_Support__c != null){
            long totalMs = DateTime.now().getTime() - c.Case_Assigned_To_Support__c.getTime();
            totalMs *= 60000;
            updates.add(new Case(
                id = c.Id,
                Support_First_response_minutes__c = totalMs
            ));
        }
    }
    //NOT COVERED END


    update updates;
}
```

My trigger is a joke, but should cover everything being inserted -- I've tried adding for loops and an else statement to the if and nothing seems to move it to being above 53%

```
@isTest
private class firstTouch {
    private static testMethod void firstTouch(){
        //Create a new test case
        Account a = new Account(name='test acc',phone='7777777777');
        insert a;
        Contact con = new Contact(accountid=a.id,email='test@test.com');
        con.FirstName = 'Testy';
        con.LastName = 'mcTest';
        insert con;
        Case c = new Case(Status = 'New', Priority = 'Medium', Description = 'Test', Last_Updated_By_Support__c = System.now(), Contact = con,
                                 Case_Assigned_To_Support__c = System.now(),
                                 Support_First_response_minutes__c = null );
        insert c;
        if(c.Support_First_response_minutes__c == null && c.Case_Assigned_To_Support__c!= null ){
            //Create a new feed item (Post) on the test case
            Feeditem fi = new feeditem();
            fi.Body = 'test Post on case';
            fi.Type = 'TextPost';
            //Create a new comment on the post in the case
            fi.ParentId = c.Id;
            insert fi ;
            FeedComment fc = new FeedComment(CommentBody = 'test', FeedItemID = fi.Id);
            fc.CommentType = 'TextComment';
            insert fc ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you insert user where Support_Team_Member__c  = true

Comment: can you point which lines are not covered?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal -- Updated to show uncovered lines

Comment: can you print and see if feedItemList is empty or not?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal it is empty while running the test, but when triggered normally it would not be.

Comment: does the test running user(probably u ) have Support_Team_Member__c  field set as true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, it helps (with questions of this nature) to provide some indication as to what lines aren't being covered.

With such a short trigger, and 53% coverage, I feel safe making an educated guess that your coverage stops after your main query: `for(Case c : [Select Id from Case where Id IN (Select ParentId FROM FeedItem WHERE Id IN: feedItemList)]){`

That'd indicate that this particular query is returning no records, and that gives us a place to start looking for an answer.

The hierarchy here is `Case` <- `FeedItem` <- `FeedComment`

`FeedComment` has a `ParentId` field, as well as a `FeedItemId` field.

In your test setup, you're populating `FeedItemId`, but your trigger is expecting `ParentId` to be populated (and to point to a `FeedItem`). This mismatch is why your query is returning 0 records.

If your `FeedComment` is going to be related to the `Case` directly, then you could cut out the middleman (`FeedItem`) in your trigger's main query (just gather `fc.ParentId`, and use `FROM Case WHERE Id IN :parentIdsFromFeedComments`).

If your `FeedComment` is only going to be related to a `FeedItem`, then your trigger needs to change to gather `fc.FeedItemId` instead of `fc.ParentId`.

Comment: You're correct on all counts -- I'm just not entirely sure how to fix that -- I'm not really proficient at writing apex tests at this point.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how to go from FeedComment -> Case without touching FeedItem?

Comment: @A_Elric I don't know if that's possible or not. If it is, then I pretty much covered all there is to know (loop over feed comments, gather the ParentIds in a set, and use it in your query). The important thing here is that you need to make sure that the Ids you're using in your query are the same as the Ids that you're gathering earlier in your trigger.

Comment: I was hoping for more explanation on what you meant here: If your FeedComment is going to be related to the Case directly, then you could cut out the middleman (FeedItem) in your trigger's main query (just gather fc.ParentId, and use FROM Case WHERE Id IN :parentIdsFromFeedComments).  

As that is the case.  I've tried that but am running into issues.

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot -- I totally got it. Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved with lots of help from @Derek F above

Trigger:

```
trigger FirstTouch on FeedComment (after insert, after update){
List<Case> updates = new List<case>();
List<FeedItem> feedItemList = new List<FeedItem>();
List<Id> parentIds = new List<id>();
Map<Id, User> userMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Support_Team_Member__c = true]);
for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
    if(userMap.containsKey(fc.InsertedById)){
        parentIds.add(fc.ParentId);
    }
}

for(Case c : [Select Id, Support_First_response_minutes__c, Case_Assigned_To_Support__c from Case where Id IN :parentIds]){
    if(c.Support_First_response_minutes__c == null && c.Case_Assigned_To_Support__c != null){
        long totalMs =  DateTime.now().getTime() - c.Case_Assigned_To_Support__c.getTime();
        totalMs *= 60000;
        updates.add(new Case(
            id = c.Id,
            Support_First_response_minutes__c = totalMs
        ));
   }
 }    
update updates;
}
```

Test:

```
@isTest
private class firstTouch {
    private static testMethod void firstTouch(){
        //Create a new test case
        Account a = new Account(name='test acc',phone='7777777777');
        insert a;
        Contact con = new Contact(accountid=a.id,email='test@test.com');
        con.FirstName = 'Damien';
        con.LastName = 'Bell';
        insert con;
        Case c = new Case(Status = 'New', Priority = 'Medium', Description = 'Test', 
                          Last_Updated_By_Support__c = System.now(), 
                          Case_Assigned_To_Support__c = System.now(), 
                          Support_First_response_minutes__c = null,
                          Contact = con
                         );
        insert c; 
        Feeditem fi = new feeditem();
        fi.Body = 'test Post on case';
        fi.Type = 'TextPost';
        //Create a new comment on the post in the case
        fi.ParentId = c.Id;
        insert fi ;
        if(c.Support_First_response_minutes__c == null && c.Case_Assigned_To_Support__c!= null ){
            FeedComment fc = new FeedComment(CommentBody = 'test', FeedItemId = fi.Id);
            fc.CommentType = 'TextComment';
            insert fc ;
        }
    }
}
```